# What do these squiggly arrows mean?

Tags: sheet-music, arpeggios

[image: What these quiggly arrows mean?]

What does these squiggly arrows mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of this squiggly vertical line symbol in guitar tablature?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43391/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-squiggly-vertical-line-symbol-in-guitar-tablature)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stagger the notes, so play them as an arpeggio, one after the other, top to bottom (as the arrow shows direction).

Comment: If there is no arrow you go bottom to top.